# If (J^T)*J is non-singular, show that J is full rank.

Tags: linear-algebra

For an assigment I had to prove the implication stated in the title. My TA says that my following proof-attempt is wrong, but I don't see why, and I didn't understand his explanation. It would be fantastic if someone can explain.

My proof goes as follows.

Assume $J^{T}J$ is non-singular. Then

$Jx = 0 \Rightarrow (J^{T}J)^{-1}J^{T}Jx = (J^{T}J)^{-1}J^{T}0 = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$

Since $Jx = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$, J is of full rank.

My TA means that I make the mistake of assuming what has to be shown (that $Jx = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$), since $Jx$ might be $0$ even though $x$ is not, and that this might be what "causes" $(J^{T}J)^{-1}J^{T}Jx$ to be $0$. I might recollect his explanation wrongly, since I myself didn't really understand the last sentence I wrote. I would think that, since matrix multiplication is associative, it holds that $((J^{T}J)^{-1}J^{T})(Jx) = ((J^{T}J)^{-1}J^{T}J)x = x$, and therefore we don't have to worry about $Jx$ (in the way the TA thinks), if that makes sense.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your proof is perfectly valid, unless I misunderstood what you meant.

Let me restate your proof more clearly. We know that $J^\mathrm{T}J$ is non-singular, and we want to prove that $J$ is also non-singular. To that end, suppose that $\mathbf{x}$ is in the kernel of $J$, i.e.,
$$J\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}.$$
This implies that 
$$\mathbf{x} = I\mathbf{x} = (J^\mathrm{T}J)^{-1}(J^\mathrm{T}J)\mathbf{x} = (J^\mathrm{T}J)^{-1}J^\mathrm{T}(J\mathbf{x}) = (J^\mathrm{T}J)^{-1}J^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0},$$
hence $\ker J = \{\mathbf{0}\}$, showing that $J$ has trivial kernel, and hence full rank.

If what I wrote above is your intended argument, then there is *nothing* wrong. You have not assumed what you needed to prove. I suspect that there is some misunderstanding between you and your TA then.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.Thank you. One thing though. I didnt write it, but J can be of any dimension, and thus when you write " we want to prove that J is also non-singular", I guess this doesn't make sense unless J is square. I think maybe you made a typo? Anyway, thanks for formulating the proof in a very nice way.

Comment: Sure. The argument doesn't change if $J$ is non-square. It wouldn't really make sense to write non-singular in that case, so full rank would be more accurate. Incidentally, full rank itself is ambiguous for non-square matrices. What you really want to specify is that $J$ has full _column_ rank here, but not necessarily full row rank.